# why is pstool-psfrag reducing pdf file size?

Tags: pdftex, external-files, psfrag, file-size, pstool

I am using pstool & psfrag (with pdflatex) to replace text in eps files generated by Adobe Illustator. I noticed that the pdf files produced by pstool (using the `\psfragfig` command) are way smaller than those I can export directly from Adobe Illustrator (AI).

For example, an AI pdf file can be 1 MB, while the pstool-psfrag pdf file is 20 kB. My figures are usually simple black-white vector graphics (graphs, etc.) with no bitmap. For export, I use very minimal settings (e.g. no thumbnail embedding, no preserved illustrator editing capability, ...) compatible with X-1a:2001 (pdf version 1.3). Other versions are similar size.

I guess the pdf image file size must have a direct impact on the final document file size, so I'm considering exporting from AI to .eps and using something like `\psfragfig{path_to_my_image}{}` even when no text replacments are needed.

To my questions:

How come there is this dramatic reduction in file size - I guess there must be a lot of unnecessary data automatically generated by AI, rigt? How does pstool & psfrag process the file - does it look for essential files? Can it leave something important out? Is there a better way, how to clean the .pdf (.eps) files when I just want to include them into my document.

**Note:** My question comes mostly from interest (everything is working fine).

Comment: I also noticed that .pdf files produced with the `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf` are smaller than those obtained  the pdflatex way. I guess this is because it incorporates only the glyphs used in the document, and not the whole font(s).

Comment: pstool/psfrag essentially don't do anythng other than call ghostscript to convert the postscript resulting from dvips including the eps into a latex generated document to pdf, so you are just comparing ghostscript against adobe's ps to pdf conversion, not normally that much size difference

Comment: @Bernard pdftex also subsets fonts usually

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If my guess is wrong then I have no explanation :o(

Comment: This reminds me of the old days in which Mathematica by default attached all fonts to any poscript file generated. I am wondering if something similar is happening here, and your conversion chain gets rid of these fonts. After all psfrag does some font replacing.

Comment: ps2pdf embeds Type 1C, compared with pdftex, which embeds Type 1.  Please try `pdffonts test.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

As an experiment, I downloaded an AI vector file. Technology of the 90s: **size 2.032KB.**
Then I opened it in AI and exported it in **PDF** and **SVG** formats: sizes of formats were reduced: **PDF** is **1,478KB** and **SVG 896KB.**

The surprising thing is that when I open the **SVG** file in **Inkscape** and then export it in **PDF** format, it results in **363 Kb** size (Why?). When I open the 2 PDF files there is no loss of quality since they are vectors. The Inkscape parameter for export indicates PDF version 1.5, option to embed fonts, and rasterization resolution 96 dpi.

**Conclusion:** I suggest to Use Inkscape for your vector graphics... and forget about the proprietary software paraphernalia.

[image]
[image]